# HTML table is rendered in one line

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, scriptish

I'm trying to generate a table dynamically using a userscript.

```
    var divWrap = document.createElement('div');
        divWrap.style.fontFamily = "sans-serif";
        divWrap.style.width = "100%";
    var spanTitle = document.createElement('span');
        spanTitle.style.marginRight = "auto";
        spanTitle.style.marginLeft = "auto";
        spanTitle.style.fontSize = "1.5em";
        spanTitle.innerHTML = "Countdown";
        divWrap.appendChild(spanTitle);
    var createTable = document.createElement('table');
        createTable.style.marginLeft = "auto";
        createTable.style.marginRight = "auto";
        createTable.style.width = "50%";
        createTable.id = "cdn_table"
        divWrap.appendChild(createTable);
    createTable.appendChild(addRow("test", "12d"));
    createTable.appendChild(addRow("test2", "24h"));
    mainDiv.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].appendChild(divWrap);

function addRow(rName, rValue) {
    console.log(rName + ": " + rValue);
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    var tName = document.createElement('td');
    tName.innerHTML = rName;
    var tValue = document.createElement('td');
    tValue.innerHTML = rValue;
    row.appendChild(tName);
    row.appendChild(tValue);
    return row;
}
```

The problem is that all elements are rendered in one line like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxUZ2.png

Is there some css value I'm missing? Or something else? I want to insert simple title and table in that thumbnail with Scriptish in Firefox..

Answer (score 1):

Tables have their own interface for adding rows/cells.

```
var t = document.createElement("table");
var r = t.insertRow(-1);
var c = r.insertCell(-1);
c.innerHTML = "Foo";
c = r.insertCell(-1);
c.innerHTML = "Bar";

document.body.appendChild(t);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tQWm8/1/

Comment: Maybe use `appendChild(document.createTextNode(...))` instead of `.innerHTML=...`.  Example code should use the least error-prone method to achieve a task.

Comment: How does `innerHTML` cause any issues? `innerText` is the one that isn't cross-browser all the time.

Comment: If people get into the habit of using innerHTML to insert text nodes, then they use it with untrusted data or plain text that contains HTML special-characters.